# Como hacer un CreateView con parámetros

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-urls

Hola mi problema es que tengo un listado de usuarios a los cuales hay que asignarle permisos específicos como asignarles una o varias agencias, uno o varios armarios entre otros, los modelos están relacionados entre si de la siguiente forma:

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Usuariospdn(models.Model):
    TIPOUSUARIO= [
        ('Conductor', 'Conductor'),
        ('Dependiente', 'Dependiente'),
    ]
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=32)  # Field name made lowercase.
    tipousuario = models.CharField(db_column='TipoUsuario', max_length=23, choices=TIPOUSUARIO, default='Conductor')  # Field name made lowercase.
    movil = models.CharField(db_column='Movil', max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qr = models.CharField(db_column='QR', max_length=12)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pin = models.IntegerField(db_column='PIN')  # Field name made lowercase.

class Usuariosagencias(models.Model):
    idusuariopdn = models.ForeignKey(Usuariospdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='idUsuarioPDN')  # Field name made lowercase.
    idagencia = models.ForeignKey(Agencias, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='IdAgencia')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechaalta = models.DateField(db_column='FechaAlta')  # Field name made lowercase.
    baja = models.BooleanField(db_column='Baja')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechabaja = models.DateField(db_column='FechaBaja', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Usuariosarmarios(models.Model):
    idusuarioagencia = models.ForeignKey(Usuariosagencias, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='idUsuarioAgencia')  # Field name made lowercase.
    idarmario = models.ForeignKey(Armarios, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idArmario')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechaalta = models.DateField(db_column='FechaAlta')  # Field name made lowercase.
    baja = models.BooleanField(db_column='Baja')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechabaja = models.DateField(db_column='FechaBaja', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Usuariospartners(models.Model):
    idusuarioarmario = models.ForeignKey(Usuariosarmarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='idUsuarioArmario')  # Field name made lowercase.
    idpartner = models.ForeignKey(Partners, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='IdPartner')  # Field name made lowercase.
    realizaentregas = models.BooleanField(db_column='RealizaEntregas')  # Field name made lowercase.
    realizarecogidas = models.BooleanField(db_column='RealizaRecogidas')  # Field name made lowercase.
    realizaconsignas = models.BooleanField(db_column='RealizaConsignas')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechaalta = models.DateField(db_column='FechaAlta')  # Field name made lowercase.
    baja = models.BooleanField(db_column='Baja')  # Field name made lowercase.
    fechabaja = models.DateField(db_column='FechaBaja', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    enviado = models.BooleanField(db_column='Enviado')  # Field name made lowercase.
    error = models.BooleanField(db_column='Error')  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Por una parte ya logre mostrar el listado de los permisos de un usuario en específico en un mismo template utilizando lo siguiente:

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def listarpermisos(request, id):
    permisos_agencias = Usuariosagencias.objects.filter(idusuariopdn=id)
    permisos_armarios = Usuariosarmarios.objects.filter(idusuarioagencia__idusuariopdn=id)
    permisos_partners = Usuariospartners.objects.filter(idusuarioarmario__idusuarioagencia__idusuariopdn=id)
```

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
path('listar_permisos/<str:id>', login_required(listarpermisos), name = 'listar_permisos')
```

Hasta aquí todo funciona bien el problema viene en las vistas para crear permisos de `Agencia`, `Armarios` o `Partner`.

Necesito que cuando entre en la opción de añadir o editar primero me tome el usuario al que quiero dar esos permisos y no tener que seleccionarlo en la lista de usuarios que me da el formulario.

Ademas y muy importante el programa me da un error una vez que añado algún permiso y se envía el formulario porque a la hora de re dirigir a listar permiso no se manda ningún parámetro para saber a que usuario tiene que listar.

Como puedo mandar el parámetro del usuario que estoy añadiéndole permisos para que me vuelva a listar sin problemas

Estas son las vistas para crear cualquiera de los tres permisos. Archivo `views.py`:

```
class CrearUsuarioPDNAgencias(CreateView):
    model : Usuariosagencias
    template_name = 'GestionPaqueteria/permisosuPDN/usuariospdnagencias/crear_usuariospdnagencias.html'
    form_class = UsuariosagenciasForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('gestionpaqueteria:listar_permisos')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De que permisos hablas? A tus modelos los consideras permisos?

Comment: Si supongamos que asignar un usuario a agencias, a armarios y a partners se consideran permisos

Comment: Django ya provee de un sistema de autorizaciones y permisos, donde puedes crear, personalizar, etc, permisos, ya sea en modelos específicos, etc. No considero de muy buena practica crear modelos y tratarlos como "permisos" o algo así. Visita la doc de Django sobre el tema: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: El caso es que los llamamos permisos por ponerle un nombre pero no son permisos como tal. es mas bien asignar los usuariospdn a agencias, armarios u partner. Lo que me pasa es que a la hora de listar no tengo problemas de como seleccionar el usuariopdn que quiero pero al utilizar la createview no se como pasar el parameto para que me vuelva a listar correctamente

Comment: He puesto una imagen para ver los tres procesos, en el primero listo sin problemas un usuarioodn, luego si voy a añadir en cualquiera de las tres tablas entro al formulario. Uno de los problemas que quiero corregir es que cuando entre al formulario ya este seleccionado el usuario en cuestión y no tener que buscarlo en el select y por ultimo el error que muestra una vez en envío el formulario

Comment: Según veo el error, no estas pasando los argumentos requeridos al la URL, por eso el error. Por otra parte quieres que ya este seleccionado el usuario que esta autenticado, en el formulario?

Comment: Si exacto, yo se que tengo que pasarle el argumento a la URL, lo que no se es como se pasa ese argumento desde la vista después de salvar el formulario. No es el usuario que esta autenticado, es un usuariopdn que no tiene nada que ver con el user que esta autenticado por eso el modelo Usuariospdn

Comment: Para pasarle los argumentos a una URL desde la vista utiliza `reverse()`, de la siguiente manera: `reverse('pattern', args=[mi_argumento])`, o puedes hacerlo por clave, nombre: `reverse('pattern', kwargs=[nombre_de_argumento = mi_argumento])`.

Comment: Si dichos modelos no tienen nada que ver con el usuario, como sabremos que usuario debe estar seleccionado por defecto???

Comment: En que hay que basarse para dejar seleccionado por defecto un usuario en el formulario?

Comment: Entonces en la vista no tengo hacer nada?? el reverse donde tiene que ir? Con el reverse le digo el id del usuariopdn al que le estoy asignando alguna agencia, armario o partners? En la función listar permisos tengo un argumento id con el cual a traves de consulta me quedo solo con un usuariopdn, y me lista las agencias, armarios o partners al que pertenece. Justo ese mismo usuario es que debe salir predeterminado en el formulario si quiero agregarles mas agencias, armarios o partners

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105747/discussion-between-julio-cesar-and-ramel-vitier-urquizu).